# wp_insert_post not inserting post

Tags: posts, wpdb, wp-insert-post

I'm trying to insert a post when a user (aka me) clicks on the button (this button is inside a meta box on the admin dashboard). This doesn't happen and I don't know why. When I put the content of my function directly in the php page, the post is inserted. But inside the function, the code doesn't seem to do anything.

My PHP

```
 add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'schedule_synopsissen_setup');

 function schedule_synopsissen_setup() {
     wp_add_dashboard_widget('schedule-synopsissen', 'Synopsissen maken', 'schedule_synopsissen_content');
 }

 function schedule_synopsissen_content() {
     ?><form action="index.php" method="post">
         <input type="submit" name="synopis_schedule" value="Synopsis maken" />
     </form>
     <?php
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['synopis_schedule'])) { schedule_synopsissen(); echo '<br>De synposis werd aangemaakt!'; }
 }

 function schedule_synopsissen() {
global $wpdb;
$result = array(
    $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}synopsis WHERE `episodeShow` LIKE 'Familie' AND `firstAired` LIKE '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . "-W" . (date('W') + 1). "-1")) . "'", 'ARRAY_A' )[0],
    $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}synopsis WHERE `episodeShow` LIKE 'Familie' AND `firstAired` LIKE '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . "-W" . (date('W') + 1). "-2")) . "'", 'ARRAY_A' )[0],
    $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}synopsis WHERE `episodeShow` LIKE 'Familie' AND `firstAired` LIKE '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . "-W" . (date('W') + 1). "-3")) . "'", 'ARRAY_A' )[0],
    $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}synopsis WHERE `episodeShow` LIKE 'Familie' AND `firstAired` LIKE '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . "-W" . (date('W') + 1). "-4")) . "'", 'ARRAY_A' )[0],
    $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}synopsis WHERE `episodeShow` LIKE 'Familie' AND `firstAired` LIKE '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . "-W" . (date('W') + 1). "-5")) . "'", 'ARRAY_A' )[0],
);
$post_excerpt = $result[0]['weekExcerpt'];
$post_content = '<p>' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
foreach ($result as $day) {
    $post_content .= '
    <h2>' . ucfirst(strftime('%A %e %B %Y', strtotime($day['firstAired']))) . ' (aflevering <div class="tooltip">' . $day['airedEpisode'] . '<span class="tooltip-content">aflevering ' . $day['airedEpisode'] . '<br>van seizoen ' . $day['airedSeason'] . '</span></div> / <div class="tooltip">' . $day['absoluteNumber'] . '<span class="tooltip-content">de ' . $day['absoluteNumber'] . 'e aflevering<br> van Familie</span></div>)

    </h2>

    ' . $day['episodeSynopsis'];
}
if ( strftime('%B', strtotime($result[0]['firstAired'])) !== strftime('%B', strtotime($result[0]['firstAired']))) {
    $post_title_month = ' ' . strftime('%e', strtotime($result[0]['firstAired']));
}
$post_title = 'SYNOPSIS | ' . $result[0]['episodeShow'] . ': ' . strftime('%e', strtotime($result[0]['firstAired'])) .  $post_title_month . ' - ' . strftime('%e', strtotime($result[4]['firstAired'])) . ' ' . strftime('%B', strtotime($result[4]['firstAired']));

wp_insert_post (array(
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_date' => strtotime(date('Y') . "-W" . (date('W')). "-5") + 75600,
    'post_content' => $post_content,
    'post_title' => $post_title,
    'post_excerpt' => $post_excerpt,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'televisie',
    'tax_input' => array(
        "programmas" => $result[0]['episodeShow'],
        "zenders" => switchShow( $result[0]['episodeShow'] ),
        ),
    'meta_input' => array(
        "layout" => 'synopsis',
        "checkboxes-infobox" => 'on',
        "checkboxes-time" => 'on',
        "checkboxes-summary" => 'on',
        "_thumbnail_id" => $result[0]['weekId'],
        ),
), true );
 }
```

Comment: It's probably because your form action is `index.php` and it needs to point to the URL of the code that processes the postdata instead.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with that, since the function kind of stands on it own and doesn't rely on the form.

Comment: Unless you have JavaScript that intercepts, the form action is critical because it tells PHP what URL to send the data to. If it's sending data to the wrong URL nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing the form tag to:

This will ensure that the form submits to the same page it is on.

Also post_title and post_content are required, so the insert will fail if either of those values are blank or missing. (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

Comment: What do you mean post_title and post_content are missing? They're there... And what to I have to change the form tag to?